# How can I unit test that my DI is configured correctly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a dotnet-core project that uses a lot of dependency injection built with things like `..Services.`[`AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_)`(someService)` during startup.

If I add a new service and add it to the constructors of other consuming services, unit test it all and then run it, I get a *runtime* failure because I've forgotten to add the new service to the service collection and it's injected as `null`.

Is there a way to unit-test that the services are all configured correctly and will be available at runtime?

---

For some extra context, this particular time round I have both an Azure Function App and an aspnet-core web app that both depend on an existing service. I modified the service to depend on a new service class, and injected it with constructor injection. The DI configuration in `Startup.cs` for both ran without error, but at runtime when that existing service was run it failed with a null reference error because the new dependency had been injected as null. (Yes I should have had a null guard in the constructor, but even that is still a runtime failure).

---

I'm sure I've seen this done somewhere but can't remember where.

Comment: An option suggested to me is to use integration tests that exercise the full app, maybe just in CI, that would also catch any DI problems.

Comment: DI verification is a large topic with [many](https://simpleinjector.org/howto+verify-the-container-s-configuration) [different](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/) [views](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/). That said, using the [VerifyOnBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovideroptions.validateonbuild) when building the service provider is a start.

Answer (score 2):

We can test the registration by using a `ServiceCollection` container.

```
private static bool ServiceRegistered(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Type serviceType, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
{
     if (serviceCollection == null)
     {
         return false;
     }

     var serviceDescriptors = serviceCollection.GetEnumerator();

     if (serviceDescriptors == null)
     {
         return false;
     }

     while (serviceDescriptors.MoveNext())
     {
         var current = serviceDescriptors.Current;

         if (current.Lifetime == serviceLifetime && current.ServiceType == serviceType)
         {
             return true;
         }
     }

     return false;
    }
```

Then we can test

```
using Xunit;
using FluentAssertions;

[InlineData(typeof(IService), ServiceLifetime.Transient)]
public void ServiceRegistrationTest(Type serviceType, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        
    services.RegisterServices();

    bool registeredServiceLifetime = ServiceRegistered(services, serviceType, serviceLifetime);
    registeredServiceLifetime.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit more explanation? I'm not entirely sure what it's testing. Would that fail if any of the service classes couldn't be instantiated?

Comment: I got the above to compile as seen here: https://gist.github.com/timabell/7ea8767e4151a56708ab0335f37696d4 but it doesn't pass because the test is missing all the environment and configuration that the real services need to be instantiated, so I didn't get as far as seeing what the test actually does. This does raise the issue that the services are configured and the test project doesn't have access to that configuration, which I hadn't considered before.

Comment: hi Tim,  testing configuration of the services may require you to split to small contextes, then user can limit the scope of the tests. My example is about testing the service life cycle.
When you want to test a service with all the environment and configuration, I think it would be better if you can try to emulate the configuration with Moq, and try many cases as you can,
When you want to test and see how application would run as it is in real time, you can have a look on SUT tests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1